# Why does updating a set in a tuple cause an error?

Tags: python, tuples

I have just tried the following in Python 2.6:

```
>>> foo = (set(),)
>>> foo[0] |= set(range(5))
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> foo
(set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),)
>>> foo[0].update(set(range(10)))
>>> foo
(set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
```

I have several questions here:

- Why does `foo[0] |= set(range(5))` update the set and throw an exception?
- why does `foo[0].update(set(range(10)))` work without a problem? Should it not have the same result as the first statement?

**Edit** Many people have pointed out, that tuples are immutable. I am aware of that. They have also pointed out, that `|=` would create a new `set` object and assign it to the tuple. That is wrong. See this:

```
>>> foo = set()
>>> bar = foo
>>> foo is bar
True
>>> foo |= set(range(5))
>>> foo
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> bar
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> foo is bar
True
```

This means that no new object has been created, but the existing one was modified. This should work with the tuple. Please note also that, although my first code throws a `TypeError`, the set within the tuple is still updated. That is the effect I am interested in. Why the `TypeError`, when the operation obviously was successful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> def f():
...   x = (set(),)
...   y = set([0])
...   x[0] |= y
...   return   
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (set)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (set)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             18 BUILD_LIST               1
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (y)

  4          27 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             30 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             33 DUP_TOPX                 2
             36 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             40 INPLACE_OR          
             41 ROT_THREE           
             42 STORE_SUBSCR        

  5          43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

This shows that the statement `x[0] |= y` is implemented by calling `x[0].__ior__(y)` and then assigning the returned value to `x[0]`.

`set` implements in-place `|=` by having `set.__ior__` return `self`.  However, the assignment to `x[0]` still takes place.  The fact that it's assigning the same value that was already there is irrelevant; it fails for the same reason that:

```
x = (set(),)
x[0] = x[0]
```

fails.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand why it works if you instead say `z = x[0]; z |= y`. If `z` and `x[0]` are the same object then it's strange that it works for one and not the other?

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: the fact that `z` and `x[0]` are the same object does not mean that `z |= y` and `x[0] |= y` should do the same thing.  Consider `x = [0]; y = 1; z = x[0]; z |= y`.

Comment: Thanks, good example. I need to sit down in a darkened room and think about this :)

Answer (score 2):

In your example `foo` is a tuple. [Tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) in python are inmutable, this means that you cannot change the reference of any tuple element - `foo[0]` in your case. Things like the following can't be done:

```
>>> x = ('foo','bar')
>>> x[0]='foo2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

You could use a `list` instead

```
>>> foo = [set(),None]
>>> foo
[set([]), None]
>>> foo[0] |= set(range(5))
>>> foo
[set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), None]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo[0] |= set(range(5))
```

doesn't work, because what you wanted to achieve is:

```
foo[0] = foo[0] | set(range(5))
```

and you can't assign new elements to an old tuple, because they are immutable. For example you cant do this:

```
x = (0, 1, 2)
x[0] = 3
```

When you are running update, you don't change references in the tuple, but only object behind the reference. You could also do this like this:

```
x = set()
y = (x,)
x.update(set(range(5))
```

as you can see you don't change the tuple, but `x` (and `y[0]`) will be changed.

```
x |= y
```

and

```
x.update(y)
```

aren't the same, because `update` works in place and `x |= y` will create a new object `(x | y)` and store it under name `x`.

Comment: OK, I am equally startled by your example now. I have no idea, why |= can't be used on a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable. By trying to assign to `foo[0]`, you are attempting to change a value that the tuple stores (a reference to a set). When you use the `update()` function, you are not changing the reference, but instead the actual set. Because the reference is the same, this is allowed.

Comment: But the documentation says `|=` is synonymous to `update`. Also, the call to `|=` does update the set, it only throws the exception afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable so u cannot reassign values to it. But if a tuple contains a mutable type such as list or set u can update them.
now in your case when u use '|=' u actually first update the set (which is a value in the tuple) then assign it to tuple which causes the exception. 
Exception is thrown after the updation of the set.

In the next case u r simply updating the set so there is no exception.
Refer to http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

> "Why the TypeError, when the operation obviously was successful?".

Because there are multiple side-effects.  Try to avoid that.

That's what the

> foo[0] |= set(range(5)) update the set and throw an exception

Correct.  First the set mutation is done.

Then the tuple mutation is attempted and fails.

> foo[0].update(set(range(10))) work without a problem?

Correct.  The set is mutated.

> Should it not have the same result as the first statement?

No.  The first statement involves explicit assignment -- changing the tuple -- which is forbidden.

The second statement updates a member of an immutable tuple, an operation that is not forbidden, but is suspicious as pushing the envelope.

**But** the Legalism Scholar argues, aren't they supposed to be the same?  Or similar?  No.

Updating the tuple object (via assignment) is forbidden.

Updating a member of an existing tuple object (via a mutator function) is not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to explain this is to show it "algebraically":

```
foo[0] |= set(range(5))
foo[0] = set.__ior__(foo[0], set(range(5)))
tuple.__setitem__(foo, 0, set.__ior__(foo[0], set(range(5))))

foo[0].update(set(range(5)))
set.__ior__(foo[0], set(range(5)))
```

As you can see, the `update` form is not the same, it modifies `foo[0]` in place. `__or__` generates a new set from the elements of the left and right operands. This is then assigned back to `foo`.

Note that for simplicity, the expansions that aren't helpful to the problem are not expanded (such as `foo[0] -> tuple.__getitem__(foo, 0)`).

The `TypeError` thrown is in `tuple.__setitem__`. `tuple` does not allow its items references to be replaced. The `update` form does not touch `foo` in any way (ie. it doesn't not invoke `tuple.__setitem__`).

Comment: But the `|=` on `foo[0]` will call `__ior__`, not `__or__` because sets are mutable, so your first line is not equivalent to `foo[0] = foo[0] | set(range(5))`.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: Right you are

Answer (score 0):

1. `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = operator.ior(a, b)`.
2. `s[i] |= b` is equivalent to `s[i] = operator.ior(s[i], b)`.
3. Item assignment on a tuple is forbidden by contract.
4. The `set.__ior__` method calls `set.update` without creating a new instance.

That explains the behaviour you are observing.

The underlying problem, is that changing the value of a tuple is a violation of contract. You should not try doing it. Since you can have any object in a tuple, there are loopholes you can exploit, but then you get the kind of weird behaviour you are observing.

Tuple items should be `frozenset` instead of `set`. If you do this, you will get a consistent behaviour, and no unwanted side-effect on error.